# Displaying value by value in a threaded binary tree using a "Next" button with a recursive inorder traversal

Tags: delphi, recursion, binary-tree, tree-traversal

As the title states, having a bit of trouble mostly with the algorithm. I have the algorithm down to parse through and print ALL the values, but I need to be able to stop on each value and display it in a label. I tried using a global variable 'count', thinking I may be able to stop it. Any ideas? This is what I have so far:

```
unit Unit4;

interface

uses
Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,           Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm4 = class(TForm)
  Createtree: TButton;
  Current: TLabel;
  RecursiveNext: TButton;
  Close: TButton;
  IterativeNext: TButton;
  Iterative: TLabel;
  procedure CloseClick(Sender: TObject);
  procedure CreatetreeClick(Sender: TObject);
  procedure RecursiveNextClick(Sender: TObject);
  procedure IterativeNextClick(Sender: TObject);
private
  { Private declarations }
public
  { Public declarations }
end;

type
 nodeptr = ^nodetype;
 nodetype = record
 id : integer ;
 left,right : nodeptr ;
 threaded : Boolean;
  end;

var
 Form4: TForm4;
 inf : textfile;
 root,c : nodeptr;
 count : integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
function Emptytree(var root : nodeptr) : Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  if root^.id <> NULL then Result := True;
end;

procedure TForm4.CloseClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 application.Terminate;
end;

function recursiveinorder(c : nodeptr) : integer;
 begin
 if c^.left <> nil then recursiveinorder(c^.left);
  Result := c^.id;
 if (c^.right <> nil) and (count > 0) then recursiveinorder(c^.right);
  count := count - 1;
 end;

function iterativeinorder(c : nodeptr) : integer;
var done : boolean;
begin
 c := root;
while c <> nil do c := c^.left;
begin
  done := false;
  while done = False do
   begin
   Result := c^.id;
    if (c^.threaded = false) and (count > 0) then
    begin
    c := c^.right;
    done := true;
    end
    else
    begin
    c := c^.right;
    if c = nil then done := true;
    end;
   end;
  end;
count := count - 1;
end;

procedure TForm4.CreatetreeClick(Sender: TObject);
var
parent, knew, c : nodeptr;

begin
 count := 0;
 new(parent);
 new(c);
 new(root);
 assignfile(inf, 'treedata.txt');
 reset(inf);
 readln(inf,root^.id);
while not eof(inf) do
  begin
  new(knew);
  readln(inf,knew^.id);
  if not Emptytree(root) then
   begin
    c:= root;
      while c <> nil do
        begin
        parent := c;
        if knew^.id < c^.id then
        c:=c^.left
      else c:= c^.right;
        end;
      if knew^.id < parent^.id then
       begin
       parent^.left := knew;
       knew^.threaded := True;
       knew^.right := parent;
       end
       else begin
         knew^.right := parent^.right;
         knew^.threaded := parent^.threaded;
         parent^.right := knew;
         parent^.threaded := false;
       end;
 end;
 if Emptytree(root) then root := knew;
end;
end;

procedure TForm4.IterativeNextClick(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  count := count + 1;
 Iterative.Caption := inttostr(iterativeinorder(root));
end;

procedure TForm4.RecursiveNextClick(Sender: TObject);
 begin
 count := count + 1;
 Current.Caption := inttostr(recursiveinorder(root));
end;

end.
```

Comment: So why not to return the `nodeptr` instead of `id` of the node and continue where did you ended by passing this returned node pointer again to the function ?

Comment: the easiest way here is to implement depth and breadth traverse alorithms for tree in separate thread. When you visit the tree node, you should trigger corresponding event. Event handler should update label and pause the thread. When you click Next button you should resume thread, so it goes to the next node;

Comment: The whole point of having a threaded tree is to **not** have to use recursion.